# <select> drop-down doesn't expand

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, expand, html-select

I've got a strange Problem, but first some description:

First there is a TreeTable - View. In each row, there is a drop-down menu in 1 column. 
The drop-down is realized via HTML  tag. And here is my problem:

- If I click with a normal click on the expand button nothing happens.
- If I click with an right click, than the menu will expand. Afterwards it works with a normal left click, too.

So I think the reason for this problem are the event listeners of the TreeTable. So I already added an if-condition and added some logging. The click is always logged, but the drop-down is still react like I've described above.

I thought i could call the expand() Method, but as far as I know, there isn't any way to toggle the expand a  drop-down, without using jQuery. (NOTE: Refactoring the size isn't a good solution)

So I'm at the end of my knowledge, maybe one of you knows an solution. Thank You.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle example from your HTML/Javascript code and add the link to your question.

Comment: @reporter: Sry its not possible, because the source code of the TreeTable is to large and just the select alone will work fine. 

But I've got some news. At the moment where the click event is fired, the dropdown has no focus. IF I set the focus via tab, it works fine. Now I've to set the focus and fire the event again. Hope that works with a <select>

Comment: Maybe you can keep the source code short if you display only the relevant structure. However, if your way does work then please post it as an answer. After that, mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an solution: at my listener I added this: target.focus(); target.click(); (target is the -Element) Now it works fine. Might I'm adding an if-condition...